# UWP: WACK test failing on Windows Runtime metadata validation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, c++-cx, wack

I have a C# app targeting Windows-10 desktop platform.The C# app calls into native component written in C++. My native C++ code has Visual C++ component extensions(C++/CX).

I am trying to run WACK test for my app & I am seeing this error:

> **Error Found:** The general metadata correctness test detected the following errors: The overloaded method **XXX** in **yyy.winmd** have the same number of in parameters without one that has DefaultOverloadAttribute. Exactly one method overload must have DefaultOverloadAttribute
>   
> **Impact if not fixed:** Windows store doesnt allow apps that don't pass Windows Runtime Metadata Validation.
>   
> **How to fix:** Please ensure that the compiler you are using to generate your Windows Runtime types is up to date with the Windows Runtime specifications

This used to work fine with VS-2015 Update 2. I installed VS-2015 Update-3 today & from then I am seeing this failure. 

 The strange thing is that the overloaded method mentioned in the **Error Report** is not overloaded at all.

I have checked this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/JJ657973.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#windows_metadata_validation) but couldnt find any solution. 

My VS details are as follows:

> MS VS Professional 2015
>   
> Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3
>   
> MS .NET Framework
>   
> Version 4.6.01038

I couldnt find any Windows Runtime Specifications anywhere. Do I need to anything additional after installing VS Update-3 ?

Comment: We would love to take a look. Could you please reach out to me at unnir at Microsoft dot com with a repro project so we can investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a VS compiler issue. Basically WACK tool is complaining about any user defined method name "**Close**"

The compiler adds an **IClosable** implementation whenever user defined ref class has an explicit destructor. It then maps the destructor to "**IClosable::Close**" method. But the compiler is not complaining about user defined method named "**Close**".

On further digging, I found that [SQLite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/384) also seem to have similar issues. This is exactly the issue which I am hitting as well.

 This is the [solution](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext/commit/863a0e611007fa4fdae03e6494fe0419c0743927) employed by SQLite. 

 After looking at the SQLite solution, I then modified my method name from "**Close**" to "**Closedb**" and now my WACK tests pass.

 As of this posting the only resolution for this issue seems like not to have a method named "**Close**" in your code.